# Top Down Bullets will not move

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, monodevelop

I have a top down shooter. The player can move in the primary 4 directions, and follows the mouse for rotation.

When I shoot, the bullets never leave the player, they just spawn on top of the player sprite.

I have tried a combination of velocity and AddForce methods, but I don't understand why the bullets never move. I have tried moving them in the Bullet's script or in the calling WeaponAttack script that Instantiates the Bullet.

***Side note for educational purposes***: Which method is better? Should the bullet govern its direction and velocity or should the Instantiating class govern it?

**PLAYER ROTATION SCRIPT**

```
public class RotateToDirection : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 mousePos;
    Camera cam;
    Rigidbody2D rid;

    void Awake () {
        rid = this.GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ();
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        rotateToDirection ();
    }

    private void rotateToDirection() {
        mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.z - cam.transform.position.z));
        rid.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, Mathf.Atan2 ((mousePos.y - transform.position.y), (mousePos.x - transform.position.x)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    }
}
```

**WEAPONATTACK (SHOOTS THE BULLET)**

```
public class WeaponAttack : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject bullet;
    public GameObject player;

    public float bulletSpeed;

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton (0)){
            attack ();
        }

    }

    public void attack(){
        Instantiate (bullet, player.transform.position, player.transform.rotation );
        //Rigidbody2D bulletInstance = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 1))) as Rigidbody2D;
        //bulletInstance.velocity = transform.forward * bulletSpeed;

        Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(bullet.GetComponent<Collider2D>(),  player.GetComponent<Collider2D>());

    }

}
```

**BULLET**

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed = 500.0f; 
    private float killTime = 1.0f;
    private Rigidbody2D body;

    void Awake() {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        killTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (killTime <= 0) {
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        } else {
            body.position = body.position * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40237/discussion-on-question-by-firemarble-top-down-bullets-will-not-move).

Answer (score -1):

```
    GameObject bulletInstance = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, player.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
    bulletInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = transform.right * bulletSpeed;
```

Comment: If you can add a bit more explanation to this, that would be great. Explain in words what the problem was, how it was solved and then include the code.